# Print message from inside AWS SageMaker endpoint

Tags: python, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I've set up an endpoint for a model in AWS SageMaker. I set up my own container and am trying to debug some path related errors. To do this I need to print some information so I know what's going on.

Is there a way to print a message either to the terminal or to AWS CloudWatch from inside the endpoint.

Update:

I'm now trying to get logger to work, I'm doing the following:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("message")
```

I optimally want this to show up in CloudWatch but currently it's not.

Comment: What container are you using? Do print() statements also not show up in CloudWatch or where you able to get it to work?

Comment: Yeah, print statements don't show up. I had build my own container off of a ubuntu:20.04 image. The above ended up working it just didn't print as expected in CloudWatch.

Comment: Using `logger = logging.getLogger("sagemaker-inference")` worked for me. It shows up in CloudWatch at the correct log-level.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but for me it still shows up as [INFO] W-9000-xxxxxxxxxxxx-stdout

Comment: Anything sent to stdout or stderr is also sent to Amazon CloudWatch Logs. I suggest running your container locally and debugging it to confirm the logs are being sent to stdout/stderr.